# Why do we need 2 variables for Semaphores in the Producer Consumer problem?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

The standard way Producer Consumer is implemented is like:

- `useQueue` mutex
- `emptyCount` semaphore of size `N`
- `fullCount` semaphore of size `N`

**produce:**

```
down(emptyCount)
down(useQueue)
putItemIntoQueue(item)
up(useQueue)
up(fullCount)
```

**consume:**

```
down(fullCount)
down(useQueue)
item ← getItemFromQueue()
up(useQueue)
up(emptyCount)
```

Where if `down` has a non-positive value, the thread waits.
`up` pushes the count up

Taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) Wikipedia article

Why can't we have something like:

```
class NewSemaphore {
    int capacity, permits;

    /**
     * Initialize the semaphore with a max capacity
     * @param n the max capacity
     */
    NewSemaphore(int n) {
        capacity = n;
        permits = 0;
    }

    /**
     * We usually never check this. Check if it's within limits.
     * If not, wait
     */
    synchronized void up() {
        if (permits >= capacity) {
            wait();
        } else {
            permits++;
            notify();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Standard down/acquire function
     */
    synchronized void down() {
        if (permits <= 0) {
            wait();
        } else {
            permits--;
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

This will be called like:

**produce:**

```
up(mySemaphore)
down(useQueue)
putItemIntoQueue(item)
up(useQueue)
```

**consume:**

```
down(mySemaphore)
down(useQueue)
item ← getItemFromQueue()
up(useQueue)
```

Why do we need 2 different variables `emptyCount` and `fullCount`?

Comment: Wjat does 'synchronized' do, because you seem to be waiting inside it?

Comment: It's the monitor which Java provides. It's for making atomic statements on the semaphore object

Answer (score 1):

No, two semaphores are not really necessary, here is a single semaphore solution written with C, check it out here:
https://github.com/heguihua/unisem

Answer (score 0):

There are two semaphores because there are two things we are keeping in check. First is that consumers wait if there is nothing to consume, and second that producers wait if the queue is full.

Your idea would let producers continue producing until they ran out of memory or some other resource.

Comment: There's an upper bound on the semaphore. It won't keep producing.